# Elasticsearch Hot Warm default

Tags: elasticsearch

When i create an index in Elasticsearch, what will be hot and warm by default?
I'd like to set up a rollover, but that's not why.

Answer (score 0):

The general idea is that you tag nodes with hot or warm, for example `node.attr.size=hot`.

Then you can create an index template so that every new index must be allocated on a hot node:

```
{
  "order": 5,
  "index_patterns": [
    "metricbeat-*"
  ],
  "settings": {
    "routing.allocation.include.size": "hot"
  }
}
```

Once you want to move the data to a hot node, you change the setting of the index to `"routing.allocation.include.size": "warm"` (for example with Index Lifecycle Management in 6.6+).